# Signing an APK failed due to accent in password?

Tags: android, react-native, android-app-signing

Im trying desperatly to build my app APK via react native / gradle but I have this error :

```
 Task :app:signReleaseBundle FAILED
```

Which is due to

```
Failed to read key ***myalias*** from store **mykey** : Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
```

So I tried to verify my password with keytool :

```
keytool -list -keystore **mykey** -storepass **mypassword**
```

and this led to :

```
erreur keytool : java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
```

But when I enter this :

```
keytool -list **mykey**
```

and enter my password manually :It works !

```
    Type de fichier de clés : JKS
Fournisseur de fichier de clés : SUN

Votre fichier de clés d'accès contient 1 entrée

***myalias***, 16 mai 2018, PrivateKeyEntry,
Empreinte du certificat (SHA1) : ************************************************************
```

So Im wondering if there is something with my password that is going wrong (it contains characters with accent like "è").

My app was developped with react native 0.63...

Any help will be appeciated ^^

Comment: Most likely somewhere in the middle of the process diacritics are lost. If this is a new application and you are trying to sign it for the first time - create a new keystore with a password and alias without letters with diacritics.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. Unfortunately my app was first published a year ago...So i can't change my keystore...